# Detecting if one voltage is bigger than another without an operation amplifier (OP-AMP)

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, comparator

I can't get my hands on an OP-AMP chip right now so I'm wondering if there's any way to detect if one voltage is greater than another voltage without the use of an OP-AMP.  I've heard differential amplifiers are a route to go but it seems impossible to effectively get a digital output out of those.

Comment: You should use an analog comparator rather than an op-amp if you want a digital output.

Comment: @Peter Bennett Most analog comparators use an op-amp in their circuit for comparing voltages.  I don't have access to an op-amp chip right now.

Comment: How accurate does it have to be? Within a volt or milli volt?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you'll need to explain the other unreasonable constraints a bit, and what you've tried. If it's not, then what *do* you have access to?- op-amps and comparators are about as cheap basic building blocks as any other part.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany This is not a homework assignment.  I am just a hobbyist for electrical engineering.  I have access to a wide variety of transistors, capacitors, resistors, and MOSFETs.  I would use an op-amp but the radio-shack near me closed down recently, and I will have to wait for shipping to get a batch of op-amps.

Comment: @DIV: An analog comparator is an IC designed specifically for use as a comparator - such as the LM339.  The schematic symbol is the same as an op-amp, but the output stage is quite different.  My intent was to suggest that if you had to buy something to compare voltages, you should buy a comparator rather than an op-amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have access to basic components such as resistors and transistors, a very effective solution here is to use two transistors configured as a long tailed pair: [See Wikipedia Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier#Long-tailed_pair)

In fact this is the input stage of almost all op-amps

(Picture Source: Wikipedia as referenced above).

[image: Long Tailed Pair]

An excellent description of how to calculate gains and component values by Analog Devices [Here](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-12)

To get a "Digital Output" just use one of the outputs. The gain should be high enough that the output switches nicely between high and low.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple low-speed comparator that will function with inputs between 0 and 3V, and provide an output suitable for CMOS logic. The transistors can be any kind of jellybean PNP and NPN parts such as 2N3906/3904, 2SA1015/2SC1815, 2N4403/2N4401 etc.

[image]

Here's the response to a 1kHz sine wave input, comparing to 3VDC.

[image]

And to 0.2VDC.

[image]